# Explanation about nested loop

Tags: sql, join, nested-loops

Nested Loop Join

In this kind of join operation it process each row from outer input and loop through all rows of inner input to search for matching row based on join column.

Nested loops joins perform a search on the inner table for each row of the outer table, typically using an index. 
example:

```
Select T1.Col2
From Table1 T1
Inner Join Table2 T2 ON T1.Col1 = T2.Col1 AND T1.Col1 between 1 AND 36
```

can you please explain which is outer input and inner input. Here we have two condition that is `T1.Col1 = T2.Col1 AND T1.Col1 between 1 AND 36 table is first filtered by which condition`

Comment: where did you find such confusing explanation of sql joins?

Comment: http://sqlcommitted.com/tag/hash-match-join/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather write the query in this way:

```
    SELECT T1.Col2
      FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.Col1 = T2.Col1 
     WHERE T1.Col1 BETWEEN 1 AND 36
```

The second condition is not a join condition, but a where condition (Table2 is not involved in solving that condition).

The optimizer of your database should be able to decide if filtering first Table1 is faster than join Table2 and then filter, I imagine that the later can be true if Table2 is quite small. Also indexes can change the query plan.

Anyway if you want to be sure about how your database is executing your query just check the query plan.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T1.Col2
      FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.Col1 = T2.Col1 
     WHERE T1.Col1 >=1 and T1.Col1<36
```

you'll find better explaination to join follow the link

```
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html
```